# Unit testing RESTAPI http response codes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Im new to unit testing so excuse my foolishness.
Do I need to create separate test cases for each response code - for each GET(), PUT()?

Unauthorized_GET_returns_403()

Get_Returns_Status_Code_200()

Unauthorized_PUT_returns_403()

Put_Returns_Status_Code_200()

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Basically you might want to test anything you care about. For a RESTful api, correct status codes might be something you and the consumers of the api strongly care about.

If you are concerned with the sheer amount of possible cases for your api, you can look out for some ways to avoid duplication. But I would start with a simple approach. When you see too much repetition coming up, you will have built a good understanding about the stuff you want to test and what your options are.